# C++ vector as class member vs in function

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

When I am using `vector` as following in a function, I get a variable D and it works.

```
 vector<int> D(100);
```

However, when I decide to use this as a class member, I get the following weird error :

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   99 |     vector<int> D(100);
      |                   ^~~
```

Could someone explain why this particular error ?
I can use array in a class as `int D[100]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default member initializer (since C++11) for [member variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) only supports equal-sign initializer (and braced-initializer, which doesn't match this use-case).

> Through a default member initializer, which is a brace or equals initializer included in the member declaration and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.

You can

```
vector<int> D = vector<int>(100);
```

Or use member intializer list. e.g.

```
struct x {
    vector<int> D;
    x() : D(100) {}
};
```

Comment: I am using member initializer list . Was wondering why such error. Thanks!

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore It causes ambiguity; in fact most compilers are trying to interprete it as a function declaration if using parentheses.